# Singleton class in swift gives EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) error

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing a swift Network Manager library specifically to cater to my own API needs. This class is declared as final and there is a static let variable to define the singleton design pattern for this class. All the other functions in this class are class functions.

Unfortunately whenever this singleton class is called and the singleton design pattern method , i.e. static let sharedInstance : NetworkManager = NetworkManager.init() is called, it gives me

> stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
>   error.

I thought that there could be an issue with the threads, but no. I just invoked the NetworkManager.shared simply in a UIViewController's viewDidLoad and it gave me the same error.

I am providing the whole code for NetworkManager class herewith

```
final class NetworkManager {

    static let sharedInstance : NetworkManager = NetworkManager.init()

    private var urlConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    private var urlSession = URLSession(configuration: sharedInstance.urlConfig)

    var basePath : String = "https://api.myjson.com/";

    private init() {

        print("This is getting called at all");
    }
    //MARK:- POST METHODS
    class func performPOST(urlString : String?, bodyParams : [String : AnyObject]? = nil, completionHandler : @escaping(Result<Data?,NetworkError>) -> Void){
        self.performJSON(urlString: urlString, bodyParams: bodyParams, method : .POST, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    class func performPOST( url : URL?, bodyParams : [String : AnyObject]? = nil, headerParams : [String : Any]? = nil,completionHandler : @escaping(Result<Data?,NetworkError>) -> Void){
        self.performJSON(url: url, bodyParams: bodyParams, method : .POST, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    class func performPOST( request : URLRequest?, completionHandler : @escaping(Result<Data?,NetworkError>) -> Void){
       self.performJSON(request: request, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    //MARK:- JSON FUNCTIONS
    class func performJSON(urlString : String?, bodyParams : [String : AnyObject]? = nil, headerParams : [String : Any]? = nil,method : MethodType = .GET , completionHandler : @escaping(Result<Data?,NetworkError>) -> Void){

        guard let urlString = urlString, let compURL = URL.init(string: NetworkManager.sharedInstance.basePath + urlString) else {
            completionHandler(.failure(.badURL))
            return
        }

        var urlReq = URLRequest.init(url: compURL, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30)

        do {
            try self.prepareTheURLRequest( request : &urlReq,
                                  bodyParams : bodyParams,
                                  headerParams : headerParams,
                                  method :method)
        }catch let error as NetworkError {
             completionHandler(.failure(error))
        }catch let error {
            completionHandler(.failure(NetworkError.unknownError(error)))
        }

        self.performJSON(request: urlReq, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    class func performJSON( url : URL?, bodyParams : [String : AnyObject]? = nil, headerParams : [String : Any]? = nil,method : MethodType = .GET,  completionHandler : @escaping(Result<Data?,NetworkError>) -> Void){
    }

    //MARK:- FIRE_THE_REQUEST
    class func performJSON( request : URLRequest?, completionHandler : @escaping(Result<Data?,NetworkError>) -> Void){
        if let req = request {
            let _ = NetworkManager.sharedInstance.urlSession.dataTask(with: req) { (data, response, error) in
                if let er = error{
                    completionHandler(.failure(NetworkError.unknownError(er)))
                }else if let resp = response{
                    do {
                        try self.validateTheResponse(response: resp)
                        completionHandler(.success(data))
                    } catch let error {
                        completionHandler(.failure(NetworkError.unknownError(error)))
                    }
                }else{
                    completionHandler(.failure(NetworkError.noResponseReceived))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK:- VALIDATE_RESPONSE
    class func validateTheResponse(response : URLResponse) throws {

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            switch statusCode {

            case 200 ... 300 :
                break
            default:
                let newError = NSError(domain: "Improper Status Code Received", code: 42, userInfo: ["statusCode":statusCode] )
                throw newError
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error received is as follows

> `` (lldb) bt
>   * thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
>       frame #0: 0x000000010deab9d3 libdispatch.dylib_dispatch_once_wait + 101
>       frame #1: 0x000000010bd00579 libswiftCore.dylibswift_once + 25   * frame #2: 0x000000010a7bfcd4 MVVMNetworkManager.sharedInstance.unsafeMutableAddressor at
>   NetworkManager.swift:25:16
>       frame #3: 0x000000010a7c010a MVVMNetworkManager.(self=0x0000600002756e20).init() at
>   NetworkManager.swift:28:30
>       frame #4: 0x000000010a7bfca0 MVVMNetworkManager.__allocating_init() at NetworkManager.swift:0
>       frame #5: 0x000000010a7bfc4c MVVMglobalinit_33_100BB9A6FE18335AA78CDFBEA4A3C62B_func0 at
>   NetworkManager.swift:25:65
>       frame #6: 0x000000010deaadb5 libdispatch.dylib_dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       frame #7: 0x000000010deac83d libdispatch.dylib_dispatch_once_callout + 66
>       frame #8: 0x000000010bd00579 libswiftCore.dylibswift_once + 25
>       frame #9: 0x000000010a7bfcd4 MVVMNetworkManager.sharedInstance.unsafeMutableAddressor at
>   NetworkManager.swift:25:16
>       frame #10: 0x000000010a7c06c3 MVVMstatic NetworkManager.performJSON(urlString="bins/9asku", bodyParams=nil,
>   headerParams=nil, method=POST, completionHandler=0x000000010a7cc650
>   MVVMpartial apply forwarder for closure #1
>   (Swift.Result, MVVM.NetworkError>) ->
>   () in MVVM.ListRequest.fetchAllLists(completionHandler:
>   (Swift.Result>,
>   MVVM.NetworkError>) -> ()) -> () at ,
>   self=0x000000010a7d89e8) at NetworkManager.swift:52:88
>       frame #11: 0x000000010a7c03fa MVVMstatic NetworkManager.performPOST(urlString="bins/9asku", bodyParams=nil,
>   completionHandler=0x000000010a7cc650 MVVMpartial apply forwarder for
>   closure #1 (Swift.Result,
>   MVVM.NetworkError>) -> () in
>   MVVM.ListRequest.fetchAllLists(completionHandler:
>   (Swift.Result>,
>   MVVM.NetworkError>) -> ()) -> () at ,
>   self=0x000000010a7d89e8) at NetworkManager.swift:38:14
>       frame #12: 0x000000010a7cc547 MVVMListRequest.fetchAllLists(completionHandler=0x000000010a7cf740
>   MVVMclosure #1 (Swift.Result>,
>   MVVM.NetworkError>) -> () in MVVM.ListPresenter.fetchAndShowList() ->
>   () at ListPresenter.swift:29, self=0x0000600002b1c3a0) at
>   ListRequest.swift:15:24
>       frame #13: 0x000000010a7cf726 MVVMListPresenter.fetchAndShowList(self=0x0000600002779140) at
>   ListPresenter.swift:29:17
>       frame #14: 0x000000010a7c5551 MVVMListVC.viewDidAppear(animated=false, self=0x00007ff125e04540) at
>   ListVC.swift:33:25
>       frame #15: 0x000000010a7c55d3 MVVM@objc ListVC.viewDidAppear(_:) at <compiler-generated>:0
>       frame #16: 0x000000010edb2536 UIKitCore-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 942
>       frame #17: 0x000000010edb521c UIKitCore__64-[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]_block_invoke + 42
>       frame #18: 0x000000010edb35ab UIKitCore-[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 75
>       frame #19: 0x000000010f3b9e05 UIKitCore_runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 634
>       frame #20: 0x000000010f3a9199 UIKitCore_cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 358
>       frame #21: 0x000000010f3c7cd9 UIKitCore__34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 142
>       frame #22: 0x000000010ca7eaec CoreFoundationCFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK + 12
>       frame #23: 0x000000010ca7e2b0 CoreFoundation__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 336
>       frame #24: 0x000000010ca78b34 CoreFoundation__CFRunLoopRun + 1252
>       frame #25: 0x000000010ca78302 CoreFoundationCFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
>       frame #26: 0x0000000114b302fe GraphicsServicesGSEventRunModal + 65
>       frame #27: 0x000000010f3aeba2 UIKitCoreUIApplicationMain + 140
>       frame #28: 0x000000010a7caceb MVVMmain at AppDelegate.swift:12:7
>       frame #29: 0x000000010df1f541 libdyld.dylib`start + 1 (lldb) ``

Comment: Unrelated but why are all first parameters in the `performPOST` methods optional? When you call this method you **do** want to pass an `URL` or an `URLRequest`. And why is the `Data` parameter of `Result` optional? The goal of the `Result` type is to get rid of optionals by returning either **non-optional** `Data` on success or **non-optional** `Error` on failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is in this line

```
private var urlSession = URLSession(configuration: sharedInstance.urlConfig)
```

As when you create an instance of class then it's variables also get allocated in memory. But here you are trying to access a variable before it's initialisation complete.

To fix crash you can change your variable `urlSession` to something like this:

```
private var urlSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now my question is , if there is a requirement where I have to define a configuration for the session itself, should I declare it static as well ( in order to prevent the re-occurence of this issue)? Or should I define it in the init method?

Comment: This completely depends on use-case if `session` should only be used or accessed by `NetworkManager` then initiating in `init` method is better idea as explained by @Joakim but if `session` will be used by some other class then make it `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Move the initialisation of your properties inside the init method. You can't access the static property `sharedInstance` when the object is being instantiated so that was what caused the crash

```
final class NetworkManager {

    static let sharedInstance = NetworkManager.init()

    private var urlConfig: URLSessionConfiguration
    private var urlSession: URLSession

    var basePath : String = "https://api.myjson.com/";

    private init() {
        urlConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        urlSession = URLSession(configuration: urlConfig)
    }

    //... rest of class
```